Why do some admission applications ask what you've been doing in the years since you left school?
Some admission applications ask what you've been doing in the years since you last left school.  For example, work, military, parenting, volunteering, or caring for a sick family member.
Some applicants might not have been doing much.  Perhaps they spent a few years on video gaming, or on Reddit, or lying in bed with depression.
They might have decided to better their life by going back to school.  Having to face such a question might only discourage them from applying.
In addition, if the question is mandatory, one could argue that it discriminates against those applicants who've spent years lying in bed with depression.  In fact, as soon as the person becomes busy with school, they now have something to do.  Therefore, their depression might possibly go into remission.  It might not return at all before they graduate.
Why do such questions exist?

I'm sorry, questions about undergraduate admissions are off-topic.

I appreciate your feedback!  I've edited the question so that it hopefully also covers law, medical, and other graduate admissions.  Could you please retract your close vote, if any?

I guess I'm wondering why you think grad school admissions wouldn't want to know what you've been doing since you graduated college ...

@AzorAhai-him-:  To avoid making the applicant feel bad — in case they've spent multiple years since college doing nothing productive at all.

I really don’t think admissions committees need to worry about making applicants “feel bad” by asking them what they’ve done with their life over the past two years. What, do you want them to just let everyone in who wants to?

@AzorAhai-him-:  Fair points.

Admissions is meant to gauge how well you fit a program and whether you'll be able to be able to successfully complete the degree.
Someone who is successfully doing other things is more likely to be able to complete a degree than someone who is not. Some decision needs to be made, not everyone will be admitted. Not everyone with depression is lying in bed or playing video games with all their time, I think that is a caricature of what the reality of depression is. If someone is so severely depressed that they have been unable to do anything for years, I do not think they are a good fit for graduate school at the moment, they should focus on their health first. I am not aware of any medical backing for the idea that enrolling in a degree program is a cure for depression.

School is definitely not a guaranteed cure for depression.  Still, if the person really isn't doing much with their time, it might help somewhat.  See, for example, the chapter of Feeling Good, by David Burns, MD, about "do-nothingism".
